# Elements are not shown with ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: wpf, itemspaneltemplate

I just try to understand the concept of the ItemsPanelTemplate. For this i built a small sample solution.

I have a UserControl "MyListView" with the following Code.

MyListView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.MyListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Padding="0" Width="100" Background="Gray">
                            <TextBlock Text="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeItemChildren}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
</UserControl>
```

In MyListView.cs I added a DependencyProperty to bind the data to that should be displayed:

```
public partial class MyListView : UserControl
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        this.TreeItemChildren = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.TreeItemChildren.Add("Text0");
        this.TreeItemChildren.Add("Text1");
        this.TreeItemChildren.Add("Text2");

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> TreeItemChildren
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(TreeItemChildrenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TreeItemChildrenProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TreeItemChildren.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeItemChildrenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TreeItemChildren", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

When I now try to use this UserControl in my MainWindow, there is no data to be displayed. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not [bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) any `ListBoxItem` properties in the control template, the `Content` is not displayed for that reason.

Usually you would replace this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
```

with:

```
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

(If the templated control is a `ContentControl` the `ContentPresenter` binds to the `Content` related properties automatically)

Also the `ListView.ItemsSource` binds to a property on the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) (which isn't set and **should not be set** since it interferes with bindings on the instances of the control), change it to *somehow* target the `UserControl` (e.g. use [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) or [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx)).

(There should be binding errors caused by the `ItemsSource` binding, learn [how to debug them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx))